# Dev-C++ is prompting me to stdio.h file every time I execute any code

Tags: c, dev-c++

I accidentally ran a normal code this morning with the only difference that instead of starting with `#include <stdio.h>`, it started as follows: `code #include <stdio.h>` and the rest of the usual stuff: `main(), etc.`. Not sure if that has something to do to what is happening right now, but it was right after that and don't really see anything else that I did differently.

Anyway, I keep getting the below tab every time I run any piece of code. I have already reinstalled Dev-C++ a couple of times, but still getting this. I am running it on a Mac using Parallels Desktop. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you guys!

[image]

Comment: When you say "you ran a code", what does that mean? Did you compile it? Did you accidentally try and execute a file?

Comment: Can you compile and run a "hello world" program?

Comment: @blackbrandt Just edited my question above for further explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @Jabberwocky I just ran: `#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}` and still same issue. It prompts me to the header file for stdio.h

Comment: Your dev-c++ is obviously broken.

Comment: ... and compiling code that starts with `code #include <stdio.h>` cannot  break your dev-c++ installation.

Comment: make sure you don't have a breakpoint set in `stdio.h`.

Comment: Hey @bolov! My question is: when I do a clean install of Dev-C++, shouldn't all the header files be reinstalled also? If not, how can I make sure the header files are fine? Thank you!

Comment: @Henry no, because Dev-C++ is not a compiler and is not a standard library implementation. You need to reinstall libstdc++. I don't know how to do that in windows.

Comment: I'm not sure what magic MinGW does that allows `#include <stdio.h>` to define `va_list`. That magic appears to have broken somehow. (`#include <stdio.h>` is not supposed to define `va_list`. It should use a reserve named type compatible with `va_list`.)

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to reinstalling Windows 10 in Parallels Desktop. Now all is working fine. In any case, thank you very much for the help guys! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the Dev C++ to a different disc or to another storage medium(HDD/SSD).
For, my case, it was also not opening even after I uninstalled and installed Dev C++ several times.
Then unlike another time, I installed it on a different disc.
It worked for me.
Hope this fixed your problem.